# angular fullcalendar change data source on resize

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fullcalendar

How do I modify the eventSource on eventResize given that the event in the callback is the new event so I can't find it in the eventSource.

```
function eventResized ( event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) {

    var end = moment(event.end).add(delta._milliseconds, 'milliseconds');
    var index = $scope.availableEvents.events.indexOf(event);
    $scope.availableEvents.events[index].end = end;

  }
```

In the code above `index = -1` rightfully so how do I find `event` in `$scope.availableEvents.events`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have same case, and I found below solution.

```
function eventResized ( event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) {

    var end = moment(event.end).add(delta._milliseconds, 'milliseconds');
    var matchedEvents = $scope.calendar.fullCalendar('clientEvents', function (existingEvent) {
                        return (existingEvent._id == event._id);
    });
    console.log(matchedEvents);
  }
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Use the `$$hashKey`.**

```
function eventResized ( event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) {

    var end = moment(event.end).add(delta._milliseconds, 'milliseconds');

    $scope.availableEvents.events.map(function(eventModel) {

        // find event by hashKey
        if (eventModel.$$hashKey === event.$$hashKey) {
             eventModel.end = end;
        }
    });
}
```

---

I ended up using a `catch-all` update function where I search by `$$hasKey` and sanitize the model by hand to make sure the events collection stays clean. Here's a more complete example (please ignore the obvious abuse of $scope, you get the idea):

```
$scope.eventResize = function(event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
    $scope.updateEvent(event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view);
};

$scope.addEvent = function (momentDate) {
    // add event today by default
    momentDate = momentDate || moment();
    $scope.events.push($scope.sanitizeEventModel({
        title: 'New Event',
        startTimestamp: momentDate.unix(),
        start: momentDate.format(),
        allDay: true,
        stick: true // prevents new events from disappearing when switching views
    }));
};

// a wrapper to update angular models properly from fullcalendar events
// additionaly cleans up dates
$scope.updateEvent = function(event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
    $scope.events.map(function(eventModel) {
        // find event by hashKey
        if (eventModel.$$hashKey === event.$$hashKey) {
            eventModel.allDay = event.allDay;
            eventModel.start = event.start;
            eventModel.end = event.end;
            $scope.sanitizeEventModel(eventModel);
        }
    });
};

$scope.sanitizeEventModel = function(eventModel) {

    eventModel.start = moment.utc(eventModel.start).format();
    eventModel.startTimestamp = moment(eventModel.start).unix();

    if (eventModel.end) {
        eventModel.end = moment.utc(eventModel.end).format();
    }

    // etc ...

    return eventModel;
};

$scope.eventSources = getEventSources();

function getEventSources() {

    // fetch pre-parsed json script template
    $scope.jsonEvents = jsonCache.get($attrs.jsonDataId);
    $scope.events = $scope.jsonEvents.events;
    $scope.events.map($scope.sanitizeEventModel);
    return [$scope.events];
}
```

Comment: note that hashkey may change if you retrieve data with this from api through network.

Comment: @cyan you are right - important notice. I had mine already prefetched as may be seen in the example.